# Error while launching xampp [Unknown Error couldn't connect to display "desktop:0"]

Tags: display, xampp

Recently I upgraded to ubuntu 17.10, now whenever I try to launch xampp it gives error:

Initially error was:

> Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: cannot open display ':0'

After this I ran:

> export DISPLAY=desktop:0

Error:

> Unknown Error couldn't connect to display "desktop:0"

Later on tried this:

> export DISPLAY=0:0

Error:

> Unknown Error couldn't connect to display "0:0

NOTE: It is showing single line error as posted above.

Comment: What command did you run to get that error?

Comment: Initially the error was : Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: cannot open display ':0' and without reading much I ran : " export DISPLAY=desktop:0 "

Comment: I don't think desktop:0 is a valid option.  =0:0

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: export DISPLAY=0:0

Comment: it is giving : Unknown Error couldn't connect to display "0:0"

Comment: You really need to post the commands and full output

Comment: If you are running wayland , wayland does not support the Display environmental variable. I am not familiar with xampp  you may need to file a bug report

Comment: I have updated the post with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `xhost +` in `/opt/lampp` or in the installed directory

 This should solve it.